# How to change the MTU size and PHY on BLE Windows UWP C++?

Tags: android, c++, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating a Windows application in C ++ that uses BLE to connect to a device using Gatt, I am following the [BLE Gatt Windows Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client) . But I have some problems since the amount of information received is not enough to establish a stable connection, I solved this problem in another API I made for Android using this function [BluetoothGatt.setPreferredPhy(int, int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#setPreferredPhy(int,%20int,%20int)) with these values:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    bluetoothGatt.setPreferredPhy(BluetoothDevice.PHY_LE_2M_MASK, BluetoothDevice.PHY_LE_2M_MASK, BluetoothDevice.PHY_OPTION_NO_PREFERRED);
}
```

and this function [BluetoothGatt.requestConnectionPriority(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#requestConnectionPriority(int)) with these parameters:

```
bluetoothGatt.requestConnectionPriority(BluetoothGatt.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

Both of them before listing services on Android Gatt API.

I have not been able to find any alternative in the case of Windows, what is the best way to increase the packet size (MTU and/or PHY layer size) and increase the priority of the connection?

Comment: There is no way to do that on Windows platform.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Is there another BLE libraries for Windows that can do that? or maybe some kind of configuration on Windows that can enable that on Windows?

Comment: It does not supported by Windows BLE driver. Does not matter which lib you will use. However you can use BLED112 USB dongle. With that you can get more control. Correction: BLED112 also does not support MTU size changing.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Is there another way to increase the amount of data transmitted (number of packages or size of packages)? My main problem is that the device is somewhat slowed down (it does not send a fluid amount of data on Windows but it does on Android doing these options), what options are there to increase the fluidity of the data in Windows?

Comment: As I wrote above there is no way to control any transmittion params. However I have never seen such issue. BT spec describes how device must instantiate the connection. It always "discuss: the MTU (and other connection params) size. The same Windows does. So internally if Windows sees that device requires lager MTU than default it increases it (if HW supports such size). The same must target device do. On other level Windows split data when sending to few packets if data is larger than MTU size (the same must target device do). If device does not split data - it is bug in its firmware.